Strict Complementary Slackness - Prove a property of the dual solution when a primal variable is zero in all optimal solutions
Consider the following linear programming problem and its dual:
\begin{align*}
    &\text{minimize } c'x && \text{maximize } p'b \\
    &\text{subject to } Ax = b, \ x \geq 0, && \text{subject to } p'A \leq c',
\end{align*}
and assume that both problems have an optimal solution. Fix some $ j $. Suppose that every optimal solution to the primal satisfies $ x_j = 0 $. Show that there exists an optimal solution $ p $ to the dual such that $ p'A_j < c_j $. (Here, $ A_j $ is the $ j $-th column of $ A $.)
This is the hint I got from a friend:
Let $ d $ be the optimal cost. Consider the problem of minimizing $-x_j$ subject to $ Ax = b $, $ x \geq 0 $, and $-c'x \geq -d$, and form its dual.
I did what the hint told me to do:
Primal:
\begin{align*}
&\text{minimize } -x_j \\
&\text{subject to } Ax = b, \\
&\hspace{45pt} -c'x \geq -d, \\
&\hspace{45pt} x \geq 0.
\end{align*}
Dual:
\begin{align*}
&\text{maximize } p'b - y \cdot d \\
&\text{subject to } p'A_k - y \cdot c_k \leq 0, \ \forall k \neq j, \\
&\hspace{45pt} p'A_j - y \cdot c_j \leq -1, \\
&\hspace{45pt} y \geq 0.
\end{align*}
But I cannot really proceed further. Any helps are appreciated.

Write out the dual please. That will help someone answer and counts as relevant work on your part.

Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/12728/strict-complementary-slackness-prove-a-property-of-the-dual-solution-when-a-pr
